# How to put DAO and GUI together with MVC

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, model-view-controller, dao

I'm creating a Java Application that represents a school. My aim is to keep the application open for new features, so I'm trying to apply some Design Patterns to it.

What I have so far is a HSQLDB connected to my program. 
In the database one can store

- pupils
- courses
- years
- exams
- grades

The current structure is as follows:

- there are classes for each of the objects that contain the attributes + setters and getters
- for each object there is a DAO that manages the CRUD operations on the DB
- each DAO implements a GenericDAO interface

If i want to create a new pupil i can call:

- PupilDao pupil = new PupilDao();
- pupil.connectToDB();
- pupil.add(new Pupil(name, age,...));
- pupil.disconnectDB();

Every DAOs connectToDB() and disconnectDB() methods point to a DBuser-Classes connect() and disconnect() methods. So if I want to change the connection, there's only one place to do so.
So far, those operations work.

My questions are the:

1.) Is the current design a proper use of DAOs? I'm asking because i would rather have one
Dao for all objects because right now there's a lot of repetitive code in the DAOs. (e.g. get, update, delete...)

Now that the DB-Access works, I want to create a GUI using Swing. I have some experience doing this although not with the MVC-Pattern.

2.) As far as I understand, the DAOs + my object classes would be the Model here. Is that correct?

3.) My understanding of MVC is that in my View-Class (i.e. the GUI) I set listeners for my actions which point to different Controller-Classes implementing the ActionListener interface and in my Controller-Classes I would for example have a actionPerformed() that creates a new Pupil (using the DAO / Model - Classes). Am I on the right track here?

4.) Is it favourable to have one big Controller managing all actions over having different Controllers?

I'm asking those questions because I read/watched a lot about patterns/OO-Design and want to make sure my understanding is correct.
Furthermore I highly appreciate your thoughts on my design! What could be done more flexible or better to maintain later?

Thanks in advance for every suggestion and sorry for the somewhat long explanation!

Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I still can't answer my questions for sure, I think I found a suitable way
for me and want to share the design (suggestions/answers are still appreciated!).

1) The applications entry-point is the main-application class (MVC.class). This class creates the
view using a main-controller. Here's the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // view is declared as class-variable
    view = new View();

    MainController mcontroll = new MainController(view);

    view.getFrame().setVisible(true);
}
```

The main-controller only takes the view as parameter as its only purpose is to display the view.
As stated in my post above my aim was to display different database tables from a HSQLDB and modify them.

2) In the menubar there are entries for managing years, courses, etc. If one entry is clicked, the controller for the clicked category (e.g. years) takes control. Here is, how the controller is changed:

```
public void addManageYearsListener(ActionListener listener) {

    mntmYears.addActionListener(listener);
}
```

The above method is located in the view class (i.e. the GUI class) but the main-controller implements the actionPerformed()-method. To do that, the main-controller calls the method defined in the view in his constructor like that:

```
public MainController(View view) {
    this.view = view;
    this.view.addManageCoursesListener(new ManageCourses());
    this.view.addManageYearsListener(new ManageYears());
}
```

The corresponding class "ManageYears" is then defined as inner class:

```
class ManageYears implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        MVC mvc = new MVC("years");

    }
}
```

What happens here is that when the menuitem is clicked, the main-controller "hears" the click (cause he is listening to it) and calls the main class again, although this time with a string as parameter. The constructor of the main class checks the string and sets the model and the controller that is needed. See here:

```
if (controller.equals("year")) {

        YearDaoImpl yearDao = new YearDaoImpl();
        YearController ycontroller = new YearController(view, yearDao);
    }
```

"controller" is the string that is passed with the constructor and "yearDao" is the Data Access Object that handles the CRUD-operations which have to do with the object "year" (which is a class itself).

So now it's possible to switch controllers at runtime.

3) The year controller sets the ActionListeners for a add and remove button in his constructor (just like the main controller did for the menu item), get's the data from the database (via the yearDao) and sets the table model in the view (view has a setTableModel()-method for that) passing the returned ResultSet as parameter of the table Model class:

```
public void showYears() {

    try {

        con = yearDao.connectToDB();
        stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM YEARS;");

        view.setTableModel(new YearTableModel(rs));
        con.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

As you can see, the yearDao has a connectToDB()-method that returns a connection (the connection is actually gotten from a c3p0 connection pool) which is then used to get a ResulSet of years from the database. The setTableModel()-method is then called setting the YearTableModel - a custom class extending AbstractTableModel and passing the ResulSet as parameter.

With the explained design it is now possible to: 
1.) only have one table in the GUI that is populated with different database outputs. 
2.) seperate the view from the data (which is what this whole fuss is about ;-)). 
3.) add new controllers or models when needed without changing a lot of code.

As mentioned at the beginning I still appreciate every suggestion or improvement! 
If you made it till the end of this post, I hope you found something to use in your own program!


regards,
Felix